# Reachability feature like in iPhone 6

Tags: applications, screen, accessibility

I've got Nexus 4 and not big enough hands to be able to fully control my phone with one hand. I've seen an amazing feature on iPhone 6 called "Reachability mode" (when home button is double tapped, whole UI shifts down to a thumb's reach).

Is there an Android app creating similar reachability mode? I don't have my phone rooted but I can do so.

For all the trolls: please don't write me 'buy an iPhone' not even Samsung, that's not the answer to this question.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I can't find any like this yet, I'm sure someone will emulate it though as it might be a useful feature. It would probably need to be a full launcher, or at least something with access to do this to any window. It may not be something immediately feasible without root initially... I guess wait and see.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, here is a research paper doing it on android before Apple implemented it, but better ;-)
Go to minute 1:05
Backpat: improving one-handed touchscreen operati…: http://youtu.be/6obUW7uhWOk

Not that the platform matters, though. It's a usability feature for a form factor after all.

Comment: Is it possible to get this or something similar somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [Xposed](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) with [One-Hand Mode module Premium (1$)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-one-handed-mode-devices-t2735815). I use it with tasker, so that a short shake activates the One-Hand mode toggle, and moves the screen 700 pixels down.